# How to fix: Nullpointer Exception at FaultTolerantChunkProcessor (Spring Batch with SCDF and docker)?

Tags: spring, docker, spring-batch, archlinux

Solved by reboot :)

I am using arch linux.

I am running a Spring Batch Job within a SCDF (Spring Cloud Dataflow) Task application. All SCDF applications are running as microservices within docker containers. I started them with docker-compose. I started getting **Nullpointer Exception at FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java** even when reverting back to a previously working version of my code.

I did update my system in the meantime...

...when I restarted, everything was working fine, again.

I suspect it was due to the way docker interacts with my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by system update and reboot.